# Retrieve values from dynamically created textboxes accessed through ContextMenu in C#

Tags: c#, textbox, contextmenu

A part of the application I'm developing uses some code to dynamically create textboxes based on the number of removable devices found from a wmi searcher.

As I want to display more information about these devices and give the user the ability to remove the device from the program itself, I've improved the textboxes in a way that for each one a small context menu is created with some extended options.

Each option is created with an event handler so that when the user clicks one, the relative operation is performed.

Now, for example, to make use of the "Remove" option I need to know which textbox has been chosen by the user and get its text, to do some stuff.

How can I achieve that? How I can know which textbox has been chosen by the user and get its text?

This is what I have so far:

```
foreach (UsbDisk disk in disks)
{
   ++count;

   TextBox[] usbTextBox = new TextBox[count];

   for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
   {
      var txt = new TextBox();
      var contextMenuUsbDev = new ContextMenuStrip();
      var ExtView = contextMenuUsbDev.Items.Add("View Extended Properties");
      var Remove = contextMenuUsbDev.Items.Add("Remove");
      ExtView.Click += ExtView_Click;
      Remove.Click += Remove_Click;
      contextMenuUsbDev.RenderMode = ToolStripRenderMode.System;
      contextMenuUsbDev.Size = new Size(211, 48);
      contextMenuUsbDev.Location = new Point(390, 240 + (i * 45));
      contextMenuUsbDev.Cursor = Cursors.Hand;

      txt.Location = new Point(390, 240 + (i * 45));
      txt.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(20)))), ((int)(((byte)(20)))), ((int)(((byte)(20)))));
      txt.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(255)))), ((int)(((byte)(255)))), ((int)(((byte)(255)))));
      txt.Size = new Size(230,45);
      txt.TabIndex = i;
      txt.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
      txt.ReadOnly = true;
      txt.Multiline = true;
      txt.WordWrap = true;
      txt.Font = new Font("Courier New", 8.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
      txt.ContextMenuStrip = contextMenuUsbDev;
      usbDevPanel.Controls.Add(txt);
      txt.AppendText(CR + count + ") " + disk.ToString());
   }
}
```

Then, below, I have the corresponding Event Handlers:

```
 void Remove_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 { // Here I must perform the operations subject of this question, in order to proceed to removal operation}

void ExtView_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
   // Here I need the same code to know with which device properties populate the form below;
   UsbDevicesProperties uDevP = new UsbDevicesProperties();

   uDevP.Show();
}
```

Anyone able to help me. please? As I searched a lot but I don't seem to find any viable solution.

Hope for your help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually use the `.Tag` property for things like this. You can put any value into that property. Put in a value that helps you identify the `TextBox` (or the data item behind it). In your context menu event handler, cast `sender` to a `ContextMenuStrip`, check that object's `SourceControl` property, cast that property value to a `TextBox` and read the `.Tag` property to determine which `TextBox` it was.

If you are creating a new `ContextMenuStrip` for each text box, you could alternatively use the `.Tag` property on either the `ContextMenuStrip` or its menu items. However, since it looks like you have the same options for each context menu, I would recommend you reuse one `ContextMenuStrip` for all the textboxes.

```
void Remove_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var contextMenu = (ContextMenuStrip) sender;
    var textBox = (TextBox) contextMenu.SourceControl;
    var tag = textBox.Tag;
    /* use tag value to determine which textbox */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually your advice pointed me to the right direction.
I didn't even need the Tag Property.

After editing my code to use only one ContextMenuStrip,

being my control a ToolStripMenuItem, could not use your solution directly, but in this way I got the text inside the TextBoxes!

```
      void Remove_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          var menuItem = (ToolStripMenuItem)sender;
          var owner = (ContextMenuStrip)menuItem.Owner;
          var text = (TextBox)owner.SourceControl;
          string diskValue = text.Text;
        }
```

Thanks!!